# C POSIX Regular Expression failure

Tags: c, regex, posix

I am trying to use POSIX regular expressions in C programming language.

I have these regular expression patterns:

```
const char *regular_expression_pattern_keyword = "^(auto|break|case|char|const|continue|default|do|double|else|enum|extern|float|for|goto|if|int|long|register|return|short|signed|sizeof|static|struct|switch|typedef|union|unsigned|void|volatile|while)";
const char *regular_expression_pattern_identifier = "^[:word:]";
const char *regular_expression_pattern_number = "^[:digit:]*";
const char *regular_expression_pattern_punctuator = "^[:punct:]";
```

To check reggae I have a function:

```
char **patterns = malloc ((sizeof (char) * 256) * 4);

patterns[0] = (char *) regular_expression_pattern_keyword;
patterns[1] = (char *) regular_expression_pattern_identifier;
patterns[2] = (char *) regular_expression_pattern_number;
patterns[3] = (char *) regular_expression_pattern_punctuator;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    regex_t regular_expression;
    int status;

    status = regcomp(&regular_expression, patterns[i], 0);

    if (status)
    {
        // FIXME: Improve error handling!
        printf("Error: Failed to compile regex!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    status = regexec(&regular_expression, "auto", 0, NULL, 0);

    if (!status)
    {
        printf("Regex status: Match ->%s\n", patterns[i]);
    }

    else if (status == REG_NOMATCH)
    {
        printf("Regex status: No match\n");
    }

    else
    {
        // FIXME: Improve error handling!
        printf("Error: Failed to match regex!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    regfree(&regular_expression);
}

free (patterns);
```

Because of reasons I don't know, this reggae check matches `auto` as `Regex status: Match ->^[:digit:]*`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to include POSIX character classes into bracketed classes: `[[:digit:]]`, `[[:punct:]]`, etc

Comment: You mean `^[[:word:]]` to match first word in the text?

Comment: The first 1 or more word characters: `^[[:word:]]+`. I think to use more or less normal syntax, you should pass `REG_EXTENDED` flag. Otherwise, you'd have to escape too many things that usually do not need escaping. `status = regcomp(&regular_expression, patterns[i], REG_EXTENDED);`

Comment: I need to match only the first word in the text. When I am trying to achieve this by using regular expression with pattern `^[[:word:]]` I am getting regular expression compile error. Also, it doesn't catch regular expression with first pattern too.

Comment: I see now, `+` is also not supported. Use [`regcomp(&regex, "^[[:alpha:]]{1,}", REG_EXTENDED);`](https://ideone.com/faCOSU). You can replace `+` with `{1,}`.

Comment: When I passed `REG_EXTENDED` regular expression with the first pattern is matched correctly. Although, word `auto` is also matched with regular expression with pattern `^[:digit:]*` which should match numbers only. Why is that so?

Comment: Again, you must place all POSIX classes into character classes - use `^[[:digit:]]` to match the first digit and `^[[:digit:]]{1,}` with `REG_EXTENDED` flag to match 1 or more digits at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Not the first digit. First number. I would like to match `123` in `123 abc`.

Comment: Check this code: http://ideone.com/6tD2sL. First number can be matched with `^[[:digit:]]{1,}`. If you do not specify `REG_EXTENDED`, use `^[[:digit:]]\{1,\}`.

Comment: `^[[:digit:]]\{1,\}` match `1ab` which is not a number at all

Comment: You want to match at a word boundary or full input string? A word boundary is \b and end of string is $. You should provide exact requirements and concrete examples that you want to match. Your regexps only check the beginning of strings now with ^.

Comment: If you want to only match the first digit sequence at the beginning of the string, I'd suggest [`"^[[:digit:]]+([^[:digit:]]|$)"`](http://ideone.com/1po6NY) (with `REG_EXTENDED`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to notice here:

- `[:digit:]` and other POSIX character classes must be used inside bracketed ("character") classes (e.g. `[[:digit:]]`), not alone. Otherwise, they match separate symbols from the class, i.e. `[:digit:]` matches 1 symbol, either `:`, or `d`, `i`, `g`, or `t`.
- To use alternation and unescaped brackets/parentheses for quantifying/grouping, you need to use `REG_EXTENDED` flag with `regcomp` to use ERE regex syntax. Without passing this flag, you are using BRE regex syntax, that is rather poor.

Now, why does `^[:digit:]*` match `auto`? Because you ask the regex engine to find **zero** or more characters, either `:`, `d`, `i`, `g`, or `t`. It does find zero such characters at the beginning of the string, thus, you have a match.

> `^[[:digit:]]\{1,\}` match `1ab` which is not a number at all

No, the pattern does not match `1ab`, it only matches `1` in `1ab` since you have not specified any *boundaries* or anchors.

To match only a  number (=digit sequence) at the beginning of a string, use

```
"^[[:digit:]]+(\\W|$)" (or "^[[:digit:]]+([^[:digit:][:alpha:]_]|$)"
```

**Do not forget to pass the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to the `regcomp` function.**

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/vCdjG9). Note that in ERE regex syntax, you can use `+` to match 1 or more characters, whereas in BRE (without `REG_EXTENDED`) you'd have to use `\{1,\}`.

Answer (score 0):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code, the `malloc` call and the following assignments doesn't do what you expect them do to.

The `malloc` call allocates 1024 (256 * 4) continuous bytes, not an array of pointers (similar to `char **`).

You don't need to dynamically allocate anything here, just declare an array of pointers, like

```
const char *patterns[] = {
    regular_expression_pattern_keyword,
    regular_expression_pattern_identifier,
    regular_expression_pattern_number,
    regular_expression_pattern_punctuator
};
```

Comment: Well, I have debugged the array. Although your provided code is cleaner, I am still having the matching issue..